# child component is not rendering using vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am getting some troubles with the render of my component! And it is funny because the data is only render when I change something on my code, and then when I reload the page it disappears!

Also, there is no error on console and the data that should be printed on table is stored correctly on vue console;

Well, this is the sequence, I have a parent component and when it is mounted() it gets the data from the database and it executes some functions after to prepare some data to be use:

```
async mounted() {
        await this.handleGetDataDatabase();
        this.distinctValuesForFilters();
        this.distinctType.forEach((value) => {this.filtersType[value] = true;});
        this.distinctClass.forEach((value) => {this.filtersClass[value] = true;});
        this.createDataForTable();
    },
```

There are two functions importants here! await this.handleGetDataDatabase() which gets the data from database and this.createDataForTable(); that treats the data to print it!

After that, it should be rendered inside a child component, this child component above that data disappears:

```
<main-table 
      :header-columns="headerTable01" 
      :first-column="distinctWeekYear" 
      :other-columns="othersColumnsTable01" 
      :row-data="dataTable" 
/>
```

and this is the data() for the props above:

```
data(){
           headerTable01: ['Week Year', 'Reach', 'Impressions', 'Spend'],
           othersColumnsTable01: ['reach', 'impressions', 'spend'],
           distinctWeekYear: [], 
           dataTable: {},
```

distinctWeekYear and dataTable is treated on those functions o mouted!

like I said, only when I update the code on vscode that the data table appers, there is no error on console, and all the data for the props is ok on console! It should work correctly

I'll put above my parent and child component. Anyone knows what I could be?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <CalendarData
            :start-date="startDate"
            :end-date="endDate"
            @update:start-date="startDate = $event"
            @update:end-date="endDate = $event"
        />
        <div v-for="(value, index) in distinctType" :key="'type-' + index">
            <FilterButtonOutline
                v-bind:FilterButtonOutlineText="value"
                v-on:event="handleFilter(value)"
                v-bind:isActive="filtersType[value]"
            />
        </div>
        <div v-for="(value, index) in distinctClass" :key="'class-' + index">
            <FilterButtonOutline
                v-bind:FilterButtonOutlineText="value"
                v-on:event="handleFilter(value)"
                v-bind:isActive="filtersClass[value]"
            />
            </div>
        <div>
            <main-table 
                :header-columns="headerTable01" 
                :first-column="distinctWeekYear" 
                :other-columns="othersColumnsTable01" 
                :row-data="dataTable" 
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import CalendarData from './CalendarData.vue';
import FilterButtonOutline from './FilterButtonOutline.vue';
import MainTable from './MainTable.vue';

export default {
    components: {
        FilterButtonOutline
        , CalendarData
        , MainTable
    },
    data() {
        // FUNCTION TO CALCULATE 30 DIAS ANTERIORES
        // const today = new Date();
        // const startDate = new Date(today.getTime() - (31 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)).toISOString().slice(0, 10);
        // const endDate = new Date(today.getTime() - (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)).toISOString().slice(0, 10);
        return {
            // main values
            startDate: '2022-05-01',
            endDate: '2022-05-30',
            dataTable: {},

            // values for create the filters
            distinctType: [],
            filtersType: {},
            distinctClass: [],
            filtersClass: {},

            // data for table01
            headerTable01: ['Week Year', 'Reach', 'Impressions', 'Spend'],
            othersColumnsTable01: ['reach', 'impressions', 'spend'],
            distinctWeekYear: [],
        }
    },
    // functions to be activated when the page is loaded
    async mounted() {
        await this.handleGetDataDatabase();
        this.distinctValuesForFilters();
        this.distinctType.forEach((value) => {this.filtersType[value] = true;});
        this.distinctClass.forEach((value) => {this.filtersClass[value] = true;});
        this.createDataForTable();
    },
    
    methods: {

        // get data from database metaseed and update inside the variable this.$store.state.dataFaceAds.data
        async handleGetDataDatabase() {
            await this.$store.dispatch('getDataDatabase')
        },

        // create lists with the distict values for the filters
        distinctValuesForFilters() {
            const data = this.$store.state.dataFaceAds.data;
            // create list for the type values
            for (const key in data) {
                const value = data[key].type;
                if (!this.distinctType.includes(value)) {this.distinctType.push(value);}
            }

            for (const key in data) {
                const value = data[key].class;
                if (!this.distinctClass.includes(value)) {this.distinctClass.push(value);}
            }
        },

        // update the data that should be printed in table
        createDataForTable() {

            // collect the raw data and create the numbers of rows according to week_number
            const data = this.$store.state.dataFaceAds.data;
            const weekNumbers = data.map(item => item.week_number);
            this.distinctWeekYear = [...new Set(weekNumbers)];

            // for each week_number distinct sum the values desired
            for (let e = 0; e < this.distinctWeekYear.length; e++){

                this.dataTable[e] = {
                    reach: 0,
                    impressions: 0,
                    spend: 0
                }

                // check if any of the filter values is false
                const shouldAddDataType = Object.values(this.filtersType).every(value => value);
                const shouldAddDataClass = Object.values(this.filtersClass).every(value => value);

                console.log(shouldAddDataType)
                console.log(shouldAddDataClass)
                
                data.filter(element => element.week_number === this.distinctWeekYear[e])
                .forEach(element => {
                    // add data only if the filter allows it
                    if (
                    (shouldAddDataType || this.filtersType[element.type]) &&
                    (shouldAddDataClass || this.filtersClass[element.class])
                    ) {
                        this.dataTable[e].reach += element.reach;
                        this.dataTable[e].impressions += element.impressions;
                        this.dataTable[e].spend += element.spend;
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        // change the filters to false or true and reload the main function
        handleFilter(value) {
            this.filtersType[value] = !this.filtersType[value];
            this.filtersClass[value] = !this.filtersClass[value];
            this.createDataForTable();
        },
        // get the from facebook database and after update the database metaseed
        async updateDataFaceAds() {
            await this.$store.dispatch('getDataFromFacebookAdd', {
                startDate: this.startDate,
                endDate: this.endDate
            })
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

child component:

```
<template>
    <table class="table table-striped table-dist-content text-center m-3">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th v-for="(column, index) in headerColumns" :key="'header-' + index">{{ column }}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(row, rowIndex) in rowData" :key="'row-' + rowIndex">
                <td class="p-0">{{ firstColumn[rowIndex] }}</td>
                <td v-for="(column, columnIndex) in otherColumns" :key="'cell-' + rowIndex + '-' + columnIndex" class="p-0">{{ row[column] }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <div class="p">Oi</div>
    </table>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        headerColumns: {
            type: Array,
            required: true,
        },
        firstColumn: {
            type: Array | Object,
            required: true,
        },
        otherColumns: {
            type: Array,
            required: true,
        },
        rowData: {
            type: Object | Array,
            required: true,
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('Main table component mounted.');
    }
};
  </script>
```

Comment: You are passing the props in kebab-case but then in child you are recieving them in camel-case. Change the kebab cases to camel cases
For eg: `:header-columns` to `:headerColumns`

Comment: thanks for your help! But I found the problem! Actually the mainTable is load before the load of data! I fixed addind a v-if="isDataReady" ;)